# Inequalities with variables that are integers

Tags: inequality

If $a, b, c, d$ are all positive integers, is it true that if $a \gt b$, and $c \gt d$, then we can say that $ac \gt bd$ ?

Comment: $$ac-bd=a(c-d)+d(a-b)>0$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because
$$ac-bd\gt ad-bd=d(a-b)\gt 0.$$